# Permissions to Configure to run interop services in Windows Server 2008 with IIS7

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis-7, interop, windows-server-2008

I have developed a code in ASP.NET 3.5 which uses interop services to generate reports in excel using visual studio 2008. The same is running very well in the local PC and the system having Windows XP. But when deployed in Windows Server 2008 it starts giving permission related issue.

Retrieving the com class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005

Any Idea on the above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Web.Config.

```
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="DomainName\administrator" password="password"/>
        <authentication mode="Windows"> </authentication>
```

Comment: I have tried the same and it works but then everytime it starts asking for the userid and password. Any other way??